# JSON select option send and send an email?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am developing a web app for my organisation, it needs to take user input add this detail to a spreadsheet so that we have trackable data and fire off an email to the user thanking them for their query. This part of the application is complete, yet I find myself stuck on the second part.

The user has a number of options to select and depending on the option selected an email should fire off to the relevant team/department with the users message.  This is where I'm stuck as it's a little beyond me in terms of development skills at this point.

You'll see my code below, the first section is my index.html (note this is developed in Google App Script):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>
    /* Base Styles -------------------- */

      * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      body {
        background: linear-gradient(0deg, white, transparent 90%);
        margin: 0;
        font: 1.5em/1.5 Arial;
      }

      h1 {
        font-size: 5.625rem; /* 90px/16px */
        color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: normal;
        line-height: 1.3;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
        margin: 12px 0 0;
      }

      h2 {
        font-size: 3.3125em; /* 53px/16px  */
        font-weight: normal;
        line-height: 1.1;
        margin: 0 0 .5em; /* 0 0 26px */
      }


      /* Main Styles --------------------- */

      .main-header {
        padding-top: 20px;
        background: linear-gradient(180deg, #141760, #007DAD, transparent 90%);
        background-size: cover;
      }

      .title {
        letter-spacing: .065em;
        font-weight: 200;
        border-bottom: 2px solid;
        margin: 0 550px 0 550px;
        padding: 10px;
      }

     .primary-content {
       padding-top: 25px;
       padding-bottom: 95px;
     }

     .primary-content,
     .main-header,
     .main-footer {
       text-align: center;
     }

     .main-footer {
       background: linear-gradient(10deg, #141760, #007DAD, #00AEEF, #55225D, #73498C, #9E005E, #CB007A, #00A651, #6D9C2D, #ED5913, #FBAD18, transparent 90%);
     }
     .input-field {
      border-radius: 10px;
      font-size: 24px;
      width: 300px;
     }
     input:focus,

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="primary-content">
      <header class="main-header">
        <p class="title">Promoting the wellbeing of</p>
        <h1>AUE</h1>
      </header>
      <div id="container" class="primary-content">
        <h2>Contact us</h2>
        <form id="responderForm">
          First Name: <input type="text" name="firstName" class="input-field"><br><br>
          Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastName" class="input-field"><br><br>
          Email: <input type="email" name="email" class="input-field"><br><br>
          <select id="service" class="input-field">
            <option class="input-field"value=""disabled selected>Please select your option:</option>
            <option id="volunteering" value="Volunteering" name="service">Volunteering</option>
            <option value="Home Help Service" name="service">Home Help Service</option>
            <option value="Befriending Service" name="service">Befriending Service</option>
            <option value="Information & Advice" name="service">Information &amp; Advice</option>
            <option value="Advocacy" name="service">Advocacy</option>
            <option value="Fundraising" name="service">Fundraising</option>
            <option value="Marketing" name="service">Marketing</option>
            <option value="Chief Executive Office" name="service">Chief Executive Office</option>
            <option value="Invoice Query" name="service">Invoice Query</option>
            <option value="Compliment" name="feedback">Compliment</option>
            <option value="Comment" name="feedback">Comment</option>
            <option value="Complaint" name="feedback">Complaint</option>
            <option value="Reference requests" name="references">Reference Requests</option>
            <option value="Reference requests" name="references">Employment Opportunities</option>
            <option value="consent" name="gdprRights">Withdraw Consent</option>
            <option value="rightoferasure" name="gdprRights">Right to Erasure</option>
            <option value="datarequest" name="gdprRights">Data Subject Access Request</option>
          </select><br><br>
          <label id="enquiry_label" class="text-label">Please enter your message below:</label><br>
            <p style="text-align: center;">&darr;</p>
            <textarea id="enquiry_form" class="text-input" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea><br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="event input-field"><br>
        </form>
      </div>
      <footer class="main-footer">
        <p>&copy; All rights reserved to Age UK Essex</p>
      </footer>
      <script>
        const myForm = document.querySelector('#responderForm');
        console.log(myForm);
        myForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let myData = {
        'first' : this.querySelector('input[name="firstName"]').value,
        'last' : this.querySelector('input[name="lastName"]').value,
        'email' : this.querySelector('input[name="email"]').value,
        'service' : this.querySelector('option[id="volunteering"]').value,
        'enquiry': this.querySelector('textarea[id="enquiry_form"]').value
        }

        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).addData(myData);
        console.dir(myData);
        })

        function onSuccess(data){
          console.log(data);
        }
     </script>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my code.gs:

```
function doGet(e){
  try {
    var output = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
    var html = output.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
    return html;
  }
  catch(e){
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({
      'error' : e
    })).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }
}

function getRandom(){
   return (new Date().getTime()).toString(36); 
}

function addData(data){
   Logger.log(data)
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1EcjX0SjZpX7qRyDuNOKdiXovgrV3au_Z8WywPIo994Y');
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Response');
   var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
   var createdDate = Date();
   var newId = getRandom();
   var holder = [data.first,data.last,data.email, createdDate, newId, data.services, data.enquiry, user];
   sheet.appendRow(holder);
   sendAnEmail(holder);
   return {
    'trackingid':newId,
    'status':true,
    'added': holder
  }

  function sendAnEmail(holder){
     var emailAddress = holder[2] || Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
     var message = '<h1>Thank you for your Enquiry '+holder[0]+'</h1><br><h4>Your message has been sent sucssesfully.</h4> <p> Your query has been forwarded to the relevant department and will be dealt with as soon as possible.</p> ';
     var docInfo = DriveApp.getFileById('1NQUEmE-CW0aTYCYMrahK1Ejv3S1DmbndLWvVMfDWV60');
     var blob = docInfo.getAs('application/pdf');
     MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, ""+holder[0]+" your Query ID: "+holder[4]+" has been received.", '',{
      htmlBody:message,
      name:'Enquiry Thanks',
    });
  }
 }
```

Super stuck if anyone can explain the answer to me that would be great.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Could you please describe what exactly you're stuck on? What is the *specific* problem you have?

Comment: @Diego I want to know how to send an email to a particular team/department when an option from the dropdown selection is chosen and the user submits their query.

Comment: I understand that, but do you know which part of your code is failing?  Have you tried going through it step-by-step?

Comment: @Diego The code as it currently stands works and I'm happy with it, all bar the styling which I'll sort once I've fixed the present issue. I'm stuck with the logic of what I'm trying to do. I was contemplating a switch statement something along the line of
switch("service"){
  case 'Volunteering':
    // email address;
    break;
}

I'm not sure if this will work or if I am over complicating it?

Comment: For looking at the comments and the question I think that you maybe have gone too much detail about the part that you have already done and very little for the part you actually needed help with. 
Please explain the setup, is the email for all the service the same (only changing the recipient)? Is there a lot of services the user can choose from? Would this list keep on expanding or require new email formats? 
The `switch` option could go crazy very fast. I usually prefer creating a dictionary and then look for the email there.

Comment: @Raserhin Thank you for your response, I actually managed to resolve this with a switch statement.  I was simply trying to evaluate the wrong expression.

Comment: Hi @APStevens could you maybe post your fix so other people may benefit from your answer. Take a look at the post about [answering your own questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1):

Please see the code below, which resolved my issue:

```
 switch(data.service){
    case 'Volunteering':
      var mailAddress = 'as@gmail.com';
      var userMessage = services[7]+'<h1>Message received from '+services[0]+' '+services[1]+'</h1><br><h4>Please see message below.</h4><br> <p>'+services[5]+'.</p> ';
      MailApp.sendEmail(mailAddress, services[7]+ ' Message ID: '+services[4]+' Received from '+services[0]+ ' '+services[1]+' regarding '+services[2], ''+services[5]);
      break;
      case 'Home Help':
      var mailAddress = 'as@gmail.com';
      var userMessage = services[7]+'<h1>Message received from '+services[0]+' '+services[1]+'</h1><br><h4>Please see message below.</h4><br> <p>'+services[5]+'.</p> ';
      MailApp.sendEmail(mailAddress, services[7]+ ' Message ID: '+services[4]+' Received from '+services[0]+ ' '+services[1]+' regarding '+services[2], ''+services[5]);
      break;
      case 'Befriending':
      var mailAddress = 'as@gmail.com';
      var userMessage = services[7]+'<h1>Message received from '+services[0]+' '+services[1]+'</h1><br><h4>Please see message below.</h4><br> <p>'+services[5]+'.</p> ';
      MailApp.sendEmail(mailAddress, services[7]+ ' Message ID: '+services[4]+' Received from '+services[0]+ ' '+services[1]+' regarding '+services[2], ''+services[5]);
      break;
      case 'Information & Advice':
      var mailAddress = 'as@gmail.com';
      var userMessage = services[7]+'<h1>Message received from '+services[0]+' '+services[1]+'</h1><br><h4>Please see message below.</h4><br> <p>'+services[5]+'.</p> ';
      MailApp.sendEmail(mailAddress, services[7]+ ' Message ID: '+services[4]+' Received from '+services[0]+ ' '+services[1]+' regarding '+services[2], ''+services[5]);
      break;
      case 'Donations':
      var mailAddress = 'as@gmail.com';
      var userMessage = services[7]+'<h1>Message received from '+services[0]+' '+services[1]+'</h1><br><h4>Please see message below.</h4><br> <p>'+services[5]+'.</p> ';
      MailApp.sendEmail(mailAddress, services[7]+ ' Message ID: '+services[4]+' Received from '+services[0]+ ' '+services[1]+' regarding '+services[2], ''+services[5]);
      break;
      case 'Fundraising':
      var mailAddress = 'as@gmail.com';
      var userMessage = services[7]+'<h1>Message received from '+services[0]+' '+services[1]+'</h1><br><h4>Please see message below.</h4><br> <p>'+services[5]+'.</p> ';
      MailApp.sendEmail(mailAddress, services[7]+ ' Message ID: '+services[4]+' Received from '+services[0]+ ' '+services[1]+' regarding '+services[2], ''+services[5]);
      case 'Media':
      var mailAddress = 'as@gmail.com';
      var userMessage = services[7]+'<h1>Message received from '+services[0]+' '+services[1]+'</h1><br><h4>Please see message below.</h4><br> <p>'+services[5]+'.</p> ';
      MailApp.sendEmail(mailAddress, services[7]+ ' Message ID: '+services[4]+' Received from '+services[0]+ ' '+services[1]+' regarding '+services[2], ''+services[5]);
      break;
      case 'Invoice Query':
      var mailAddress = 'as@gmail.com';
      var userMessage = services[7]+'<h1>Message received from '+services[0]+' '+services[1]+'</h1><br><h4>Please see message below.</h4><br> <p>'+services[5]+'.</p> ';
      MailApp.sendEmail(mailAddress, services[7]+ ' Message ID: '+services[4]+' Received from '+services[0]+ ' '+services[1]+' regarding '+services[2], ''+services[5]);
      break;
      case 'Compliment':
      var mailAddress = 'as@gmail.com';
      var userMessage = services[7]+'<h1>Message received from '+services[0]+' '+services[1]+'</h1><br><h4>Please see message below.</h4><br> <p>'+services[5]+'.</p> ';
      MailApp.sendEmail(mailAddress, services[7]+ ' Message ID: '+services[4]+' Received from '+services[0]+ ' '+services[1]+' regarding '+services[2], ''+services[5]);
      break;
      case 'Consent':
      var mailAddress = 'as@gmail.com';
      var userMessage = services[7]+'<h1>Message received from '+services[0]+' '+services[1]+'</h1><br><h4>Please see message below.</h4><br> <p>'+services[5]+'.</p> ';
      MailApp.sendEmail(mailAddress, services[7]+ ' Message ID: '+services[4]+' Received from '+services[0]+ ' '+services[1]+' regarding '+services[2], ''+services[5]);
      break;
      case 'other':
      var mailAddress = 'as@gmail.com';
      var userMessage = services[7]+'<h1>Message received from '+services[0]+' '+services[1]+'</h1><br><h4>Please see message below.</h4><br> <p>'+services[5]+'.</p> ';
      MailApp.sendEmail(mailAddress, services[7]+ ' Message ID: '+services[4]+' Received from '+services[0]+ ' '+services[1]+' regarding '+services[2], ''+services[5]);
      break;
  }
```